# How to Rank Values in Dataframe Relative to Other Values in a Particular Year in a Dataframe with Multiple Years?

Tags: r, ranking

I am having a problem in R with ranking countries by their average consumption income in 1950 using the Penn World Table Data. I have multiple years (i.e. from 1950-1959) in the data for all the countries.

The main thing I want to do is rank income for countries relative to other countries by year. I tried to use `ifelse()` and `percent_rank()` functions together but it didn’t work correctly (it just ranks a country’s income relative to other countries' income in all of the years).

Below is the R code:

```
install.packages("pwt10","dplyr")
library(pwt10)
data(pwt10.01)
library(dplyr)

PWT1950 <- subset(pwt10.01, pwt10.01$year %in% c("1950","1951","1952","1953","1954","1955","1956","1957","1958","1959") & i_cig %in% c("benchmark","extrapolated","interpolated") & i_xr=="market")

PWT1950$IncomeRank <- ifelse(PWT1950$year==1950,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1951,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1952,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1953,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1954,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1955,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1956,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1957,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1958,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1959,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop)))))))))))
```

I was expecting that after inputting the commands listed previously that this command `subset(PWT1950,year==1959,select=c(IncomeRank,country))` would give me same result:

```
PWT1959 <- subset(pwt10.01,year=="1959" & i_cig %in% c("benchmark","extrapolated","interpolated") & i_xr=="market")
PWT1959$IncomeRank <- percent_rank(PWT1959$ccon/PWT1959$pop)
subset(PWT1959,select=c(IncomeRank,country))
```

Considering the two commands are giving me different results I suspect I made a mistake earlier.

Comment: I haven't installed the package to get your data, but with `library(dplyr)` something like `pwt10.01 |> filter(year %in% 1950:1959 & i_cig %in% c("benchmark","extrapolated","interpolated") & i_xr=="market") |> mutate(IncomeRank = percent_rank(ccon/pop), .by = year)` should do it. Note the `.by`, the `mutate` operation will be done "by group" defined in `.by`, no need for manually making subsets for each group. You may want to include `i_cig` in the `.by`, not sure without seeing your data and an expected output.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks very much! I can confirm this works! But I was also wondering how to apply this to Nominal (Nominal here refers to Market Exchange Rates instead of the PPP Exchange Rates which are used by Default in Penn World Table) Income Comparison. For example here is code:
```PWT1950$IncomeRank <- ifelse(PWT1950$year==1950,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon*PWT1950$pl_con/PWT1950[PWT1950$year==1950 & PWT1950$isocode=="USA","pl_con"]/PWT1950$pop),

ifelse(PWT1950$year==1951,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon*PWT1950$pl_con/PWT1950[PWT1950$year==1951 & PWT1950$isocode=="USA","pl_con"]/PWT1950$pop)```

Comment: @GregorThomas Only Difference between this and Earlier is I am multiplying CCON with Consumption Price Level (pl_c) of the Country Relative to USA (pl_c of USA).

Comment: @GregorThomas Sorry to bother you but I inputted the commands you mentioned earlier now and  I am seem to be getting "Error: object 'year' not found". Not sure how to interpert this...

Comment: If it worked before and now it doesn't then one of two things happened (a) the `year` column in your data got dropped. If this is the case, reload your data and try again. (b) Some other version of `mutate()` **not** from the `dplyr` package got loaded and is masking the `dplyr::mutate()` you want to be using. Either call `dplyr::mutate()` like that to make sure you get the `dplyr` version, or restart R and try again.

Comment: As for the USA multiplication, something like `PWT1950 |> mutate(Nominal_Income_Rank = percent_rank(ccon * pl_con / pl_con[isocode == "USA"] / pop))`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I figured out on my own that I just needed to unload the `dplyr` package with `detach` and reload it with `library` to make it work. Not sure why doing this makes it work. But I would still like help with the Nominal Income Comparison if you know the commands on how to do it. Thanks for all the help you given me previously. I appreciate it immensly.

Comment: @GregorThomas Nice all seems to be working now. I guess the question is answered now. Thanks for all the valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GregorThomas solution to this question was fund. What fixed the issue was to use:

```
pwt10.01 |> 
  filter(year %in% 1950:1959 & i_cig %in% c("benchmark","extrapolated","interpolated") & i_xr=="market") |>
  mutate(IncomeRank = percent_rank(ccon/pop), .by = year)
```

instead of:

```
PWT1950$IncomeRank <- ifelse(PWT1950$year==1950,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1951,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1952,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1953,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1954,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1955,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1956,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1957,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1958,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
ifelse(PWT1950$year==1959,percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop),
percent_rank(PWT1950$ccon/PWT1950$pop)))))))))))
```

For Comparing Nominal Incomes the command is `PWT1950 |> mutate(Nominal_Income_Rank = percent_rank(ccon * pl_con / pl_con[isocode == "USA"] / pop))`

Thanks for All The Help GregorThomas. I seriously appreciate it.